# Problems with dynamic DNS and Raspberry Pi

Tags: server, remote, ethernet, communication

I've bumped into the weirdest problem with dynamic DNS and Raspberry Pi.

Here's my setup:

- Raspberry Pi has IP address 172.16.1.*xxx*
- Raspberry Pi is in DMZ
- I'm using DynDNS to point *whatever*.dyndns.org at my Raspberry Pi.

Here's where things break down. If phone is on the same network as the Raspberry Pi and I go  to 172.16.1.*xxx*, boom! the Raspberry Pi pops up. If I try going to *whatever*.dyndns.org while I'm on the same LAN as the Raspberry Pi, the browser says website not found.

Then, if I connect to cellular data and go to *whatever*.dyndns.org, the Raspberry Pi responds as if nothing was wrong. If I try the same from work or the WiFi at the coffee shop or from a friend's place, everything works OK.

Here's what's bothering me. Why can I not access *whatever*.dyndns.org from inside the LAN but I can from outside? What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: My router/gateway is an Actiontec V1000H provided by my ISP. I have to use this since I'm on a fibre optic connection. (I asked them for a DSL connection over twisted pair. They said all new connections are FO.)

UPDATE: So it is my router. It does not support NAT loopback, and it does not support bridged setup. I'm going to investigate if I can use an off-the-shelf router. Looks unlikely. :(

Comment: is your connection to the pi NATed? if so, you can try to enable the NAT loopback...

Comment: How do I add a NAT loopback? I think I know what you are saying, however, I am not an expert at iptables.

Thank you.

Comment: you normally set this on your router (note: not every router supports nat loopback), please update your question and give more details of your setup

Comment: So I'm using an ISP-provided Actiontec V1000H. Gathering everything I've read on other forums, this "award winning" router doesn't support NAT loopback. I'm going to check if I can use an off-the-shelf router that's more capable with my fibre optic setup. As it stands right now, I'm pretty much S.O.L.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I found out that the issue lies in the fact that my router does not support NAT loopback. This is not a problem with the configuration of the Raspberry Pi.

UPDATE

So I fixed my problem using a hack.

I got a new router, flashed OpenWRT, set it in bridge mode and configured it to return the internal IP address of the Raspberry Pi (172.16.1.*xxx*) when a device inside the LAN does a DNS lookup for *whatever*.dyndns.org. I disabled the WiFi hotspot on my ISP's router and I use the OpenWRT router as the WiFi hotspot.

The net effect is that DNS lookup for *whatever*.dyndns.org returns

- 172.16.1.*xxx* inside the LAN (since everything in my home except the Raspberry Pi connects to the net via WiFi)
- my public IP address when outside the LAN

Comment: OW man, I looking to do EXACTLY that on my home.. I want my pictures to load from the raspi at LAN speed. Whats the name I should be looking for in my router configuration? NAT loopback? I can set NAT (I use that for the webserver) but didn't know I can tweak the DNS